# What nonlocal effects can change the performance of a basic block?

Tags: optimization, assembly, compilation, x86, micro-optimization

A [**Basic Block**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) is an assembly snippet with only one entrance point and one exit point (the Wikipedia link also has a more rigorous definition). Many compiler optimization passes rely on the compiler breaking the user's code down into basic blocks before giving them to the optimizer.

I'm curious to know what nonlocal effects can affect performance of a basic block itself. By nonlocal effects I mean how code outside the basic block run before it may affect its running time, or how where the code is laid out in memory may affect it. This is a bit more restrictive than worrying about performance of arbitrary programs with looping, branching, etc.

Off the top of my head cache use by other parts of the program, both memory and instruction cache, seems like the biggest possible nonlocal effect. Also the state of the pipeline setup by previously executed instructions or earlier instructions currently in flight. I'm interested in x86/x86-64 specifically but effects on other architectures seem worth knowing too. Are there other nonlocal effects?

Comment: Besides what Ira mentioned, there's I-cache pressure.  Especially on Intel SnB-family CPUs, running from uop-cache instead of the decoders can matter when the frontend is a potential bottleneck (i.e. high IPC).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a short list:

- Location of code and data in memory heirarchy
- Cache line effects
- Other threads executing in parallel
- Locks and other synchronization
- Interrupts (from I/O devices or OS trap calls)
- Page faults due to access patterns
- Data access dependencies (same vs. not same memory address)
- Write serialization/coherency

Have fun with these.

Answer (score 0):

If the basic block contains a function call, that's a big unknown.

Comment: A basic block can't contain a function call. The function call would be an exit.

Comment: @Joseph: I checked into that [*here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block), and the most it says is "Function calls can be at the end of a basic block if they cannot return, such as functions which throw exceptions or special calls like C's longjmp and exit". It appears to allow vanilla function calls to appear within basic blocks, though it does exclude jumps and returns.